# How to update columns in existing table by using temporary table columns in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql-update, amazon-redshift

Below code is developed in SQL to update target table columns. Can some one help me to rewrite below query in redshift as I am trying to execute same query on amazon redshift it is giving error as:

> Amazon Invalid operation: relation "c" does not exist;

```
With TempTable As
(
        SELECT   Left('abcdefghijk',len(TerritoryName)/3) +  Substring(TerritoryName,len(TerritoryName)-len(TerritoryName)/3-len(TerritoryName)/3+1,len(TerritoryName)-len(TerritoryName)/3-len(TerritoryName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(TerritoryName)/3) As Masked_TerritoryName
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(DistrictName)/3) +  Substring(DistrictName,len(DistrictName)-len(DistrictName)/3-len(DistrictName)/3+1,len(DistrictName)-len(DistrictName)/3-len(DistrictName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(DistrictName)/3) As Masked_DistrictName
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(RegionName)/3) +  Substring(RegionName,len(RegionName)-len(RegionName)/3-len(RegionName)/3+1,len(RegionName)-len(RegionName)/3-len(RegionName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(RegionName)/3) As Masked_RegionName
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(RSMTerritoryName)/3) +  Substring(RSMTerritoryName,len(RSMTerritoryName)-len(RSMTerritoryName)/3-len(RSMTerritoryName)/3+1,len(RSMTerritoryName)-len(RSMTerritoryName)/3-len(RSMTerritoryName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(RSMTerritoryName)/3) As Masked_RSMTerritoryName
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(CCAName)/3) +  Substring(CCAName,len(CCAName)-len(CCAName)/3-len(CCAName)/3+1,len(CCAName)-len(CCAName)/3-len(CCAName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(CCAName)/3) As Masked_CCAName
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(LCAName)/3) +  Substring(LCAName,len(LCAName)-len(LCAName)/3-len(LCAName)/3+1,len(LCAName)-len(LCAName)/3-len(LCAName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(LCAName)/3) As Masked_LCAName
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(TMComp)/3) +  Substring(TMComp,len(TMComp)-len(TMComp)/3-len(TMComp)/3+1,len(TMComp)-len(TMComp)/3-len(TMComp)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(TMComp)/3) As Masked_TMComp
                ,Left('abcdefghijk',len(ASMTerritoryName)/3) +  Substring(ASMTerritoryName,len(ASMTerritoryName)-len(ASMTerritoryName)/3-len(ASMTerritoryName)/3+1,len(ASMTerritoryName)-len(ASMTerritoryName)/3-len(ASMTerritoryName)/3) + Right('ijklmnopqrstuv',len(ASMTerritoryName)/3) As Masked_ASMTerritoryName
                ,TerritoryCode      
        FROM TargetTable
)
    Update C
    Set      C.TerritoryName = N.Masked_TerritoryName
            ,C.DistrictName = N.Masked_DistrictName
            ,C.RegionName = N.Masked_RegionName
            ,C.RSMTerritoryName = N.Masked_RSMTerritoryName
            ,C.CCAName = N.Masked_CCAName
            ,C.LCAName = N.Masked_LCAName
            ,C.TMComp = N.Masked_TMComp
            ,C.ASMTerritoryName = N.Masked_ASMTerritoryName
    From TargetTable C
        Inner Join TempTable N ON C.TerritoryCode = N.TerritoryCode
```

Comment: Please tag only a single RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use just an alias for the target table.  You have "... Update C ...", I expect you need "... Update TargetTable ..." or "... Update TargetTable C ...".

Also you don't need to list TargetTable in the FROM clause as this is assumed.  Your join on conditions become where conditions.  So you query will look like this:

```
With TempTable As
(
        SELECT ...
        FROM TargetTable
)
Update TargetTable C
    Set      ...
From TempTable N
Where C.TerritoryCode = N.TerritoryCode
```